# Rephrasing a sentence using 'unless'

Tags: unless

How do you rephrase this sentence using 'unless':

> When my brother is not in a good mood, he will keep his bedroom door shut.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for writing advice which will not be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

My brother will keep his bedroom door shut unless he is in a good mood.